# How to setup nested routes using react-router to load nested contexts using ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-context

I need to implement a nested routing mechanism using `react-router` synced with context loading in React.

The idea is to load modules, and for every module load pages on it.

On application load (`App`), I need to load the `appContext`.

For every module change, I need to reload the `moduleContext`, but **WITHOUT RELOADING** the `appContext` again.

In short steps:

1. Load `appContext` on application load
2. Load `moduleContext` on default module load
3. Another page from same module ==> loads nothing, as it has both valid contexts
4. Another page from another module ==> loads `moduleContext` only, as `appContext` remains valid

Here are my components:

```
class App extends Component {
    render = () => {
        let routes = null;
        if (!isAuthenticated()) {
            routes = <Auth />;
        } else {
            routes = (
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/logout" render={() => logout()} />
                    <Route exact path="/auth" render={() => logout()} />

                    <Route component={AppLoader} />
                </Switch>
            );
        }

        return <BrowserRouter>{routes}</BrowserRouter>;
    };
}

class AppLoader extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <AppContextLoader>
                <ModulesLoader {...this.props} />
            </AppContextLoader>
        );
    };
}

class ModulesLoader extends Component {
    render = () => {
        let { location } = this.props;

        return (
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        path="/module1"
                        render={props => <Module module="module1" />}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/module2"
                        render={props => <Module module="module2" />}
                    />
                </Switch>
        );
    };
}

class Module extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        module: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    };

    render = () => {
        let { module } = this.props;

        return (
            <ModuleContextLoader module={module}>
                <h1>Load Page Here</h1>
            </ModuleContextLoader>
        );
    };
}
```

My problem is that on every page change I'm reloading `appContext` and `moduleContext`
and this is not the expected behaviour.

How to a properly nest the router in order to achieve my desired results?

Comment: can you provide codesandbox for that?

Comment: for nested routing please see https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting. in your routes you can lazy load your components with React.lazy

Comment: Switches render routes exclusively, i.e. only the first matching route. If you need multiple components/routes rendered concurrently then you need to use a router instead. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch